# Delta method and clustered standard errors

Tags: r

I have a question regarding how to apply the delta method when I have clustered standard errors. Consider the following dataset and (simple) regression ((Please note that this question is not necessarily about whether it makes sense to cluster around "us" or the correctness / usefulness of this regression).

```
#Use packages
library(multiwayvcov)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
library(msm)

#load the data
data(mtcars)


# Run the regression
model1<-lm(mpg~cyl+gear+drat, data = mtcars)

#Calculate variance covariance matrix for clustered standard errors
vcov<-cluster.vcov(model1, mtcars$vs)
coeftest(model1, vcov)

# Apply delta method results in error
g<-model1$coefficients[2] / model1$coefficients[1]

deltamethod(g, mean, cov = vcov, ses=TRUE)


# Error I get is this one: "Error in deltamethod(g, mean = g, cov = vcov, ses = TRUE) : 
#  Covariances should be a  1  by  1  matrix"
```

Now I want to calculate the standard error for the coefficient (cyl) divided by (intercept) when using my matrix for clustered standard errors around "vs" (i.e. the vcov matrix). Does anyone know how to do this? I looked at this website, but for some reason I got an error when applying this (https://rdrr.io/rforge/msm/man/deltamethod.html). I appreciate any help.

Comment: How did you apply the method? What error did you get? It is hard to see what you did wrong, without a reproducible example.

Comment: Hello Oliver, sorry for the incompleteness of my question. Hopefully this helps. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Look at the help, `?deltamethod`. The first argument should be a formula, you've provided a ratio of two numbers.

Comment: Hello Pseudospin, you were right. I ran it correctly in my R, but typed it wrongly in my question here. The error remains the same when I plug in "g" instead of the fraction. So I am still not sure what I should change here. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just editing the `deltamethod` call to output an answer - I don't know if this answer actually makes sense for what you want to do.

```
deltamethod(
  g = formula('~x2/x1'), 
  mean = model1$coefficients, 
  cov = vcov, 
  ses = TRUE)
```